# How calculate the distance of all point inside a square?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, geometry, amplitude

I Have an issue to create some geometries inside a phantom with **Filed II framework.** I did create a circle, but now I have problem to create a square inside the phantom.

It is the following code to produce it in Matlab. The line of code that produce inside, is my issue. For the circle, I did calculate the distance of two points inside the circle and when it is less than the radius of the circle, they are inside the circle. But I have problem for triangle or square.

```
Phantom.x_size = 50/1000; % Width of phantom [mm]
Phantom.y_size = 10/1000; % Transverse width of phantom [mm]
Phantom.z_size = 60/1000; % Height of phantom [mm]
Phantom.z_start = 30/1000; % Start of phantom surface [mm];

N = Calculate_number_of_scatterers(Phantom);
N = 1000*ceil(N/1000);

% Create the general scatterers
x = (rand (N,1)-0.5)*Phantom.x_size;
y = (rand (N,1)-0.5)*Phantom.y_size;
z = rand (N,1)*Phantom.z_size + Phantom.z_start;

% Generate the amplitudes with a Gaussian distribution
amplitudes = randn(N,1);

%Make the cyst
r = 8/2/1000; %radius of cyst[mm]
xc = 10/1000; %place of the cyst
zc = 40/1000 + Phantom.z_start;
% [in,out] = inpolygon(xc,zc,x,z); 
inside = ( ((x-xc).^2 + (z-zc).^2) < r^2); % scatteres inside the cyst
amplitudes = amplitudes .* (1-inside); % amplitude of the scatteres inside the cyst
Phantom.positions = [x y z];
Phantom.amplitudes = amplitudes;
figure; 
plot3(Phantom.positions(:,1), Phantom.positions(:,3),Phantom.amplitudes,'.')
```

Comment: have you looked at `inpolygon` https://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/inpolygon.html ?

Comment: I tried to fix your formatting and grammar a little bit, I hope I didn’t change any meaning.

Comment: `inside` is a boolean value (true/false). What does it mean to multiply the amplitudes with that?

Comment: It's making the scatters inside the cyst (circle) different with the general scatters.

Comment: Please note that the "square" tag is in regard to APIs for the [*Square POS software*](https://squareup.com), not the geometric figure so you should remove it. ;-)